# How do I open an href link in HTML to a file but not download the file in a Flask app

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm using Flask and AutoIndex. When I go to the URL for the directory I specified with AutoIndex, I can see the files in the directory just fine. But when I click on a file to view it, the browser automatically downloads the file. I just want it to display as a plain text file when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory), example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/open')
def open():
    """Open in browser"""
    return send_from_directory('/tmp/', 'hello.txt')


@app.route('/download')
def download():
    """Download"""
    return send_from_directory('/tmp/', 'hello.txt', as_attachment=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the response to set the content-type header to 'text/plain', and maybe also remove or rewrite the [content-disposition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) header.

You might need to create a new view to serve the files like that and change or configure AutoIndex to point the links to your view.